# Can this narrowing down a list be done more easily, using different comparing methods or maybe my way of determining the parameters is too slow?

Tags: c

**How the List is Narrowed Down:**

1. Adjusts the director's birth date for leap years.
2. Calculates the "A1"    value for the director.
3. Compares each candidate's birth date with the director's birth date using the "A1" value.
4. Eliminates candidates based on birth year and a comparison with the director's birth year.
5. Modifies the input array by removing candidates that do not meet the criteria.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Date { 
    int day, month, year;
};

struct Employee {
    char name_surname[50];
    struct Date birth_date;
};

int month(int m) {
    if (m < 0)
        m *= -1;
    if (m == 1) return 0;
    if (m == 2) return 31;
    if (m == 3) return 59;
    if (m == 4) return 90;
    if (m == 5) return 120;
    if (m == 6) return 151;
    if (m == 7) return 181;
    if (m == 8) return 212;
    if (m == 9) return 243;
    if (m == 10) return 273;
    if (m == 11) return 304;
    if (m == 12) return 334;

    return 0;
}

int divisible(int x) {
    if (x % 4 == 0) {
        if (x % 400 == 0)
            return 1;
        else if (x % 100)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int is_letter(char c) {
    if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'))
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

int narrow_down_list(struct Employee* candidates, int size, struct Employee director, int num_days) {
    struct Employee* ptr;
    double s = 0, A;
    if (divisible(director.birth_date.year) && director.birth_date.month > 2)
        director.birth_date.day++;
        
    int A1 = director.birth_date.day + month(director.birth_date.month);
    A = director.birth_date.day + month(director.birth_date.month) - num_days;
    int A2;
    while (A <= 0) {
        director.birth_date.year--;
        A += 365;
        A1 = A + director.birth_date.day;
    }
    int num = 0;
    int temp1 = 0;
    int temp2 = 0;
    int upper_case = 0, upper_case2 = 0;
    do {
        num++;
    } while (director.name_surname[num] != ' ');
    do {
        temp1++;
        if (director.name_surname[temp1 + num] == ' ') {
            num += temp1;
            temp1 = 1;
        }
    } while (is_letter(director.name_surname[temp1 + num]));

    if (director.name_surname[temp1 + num] == '-') {
        upper_case = 1;
        do {
            temp2++;
        } while (is_letter(director.name_surname[temp2 + temp1 + num]));
    }
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    int temp3;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;

        do {
            x++;
        } while (candidates->name_surname[x] != ' ');
        do {
            y++;
            if (candidates->name_surname[x + y] == ' ') {
                x += y;
                y = 0;
            }
            if (candidates->name_surname[x + y] == '-') {
                upper_case2 = 1;
                break;
            }
        } while (candidates->name_surname[x + y] != 0);

        temp3 = 0;
        j = 0;
        while (j < temp1) {
            if (director.name_surname[num + j] != candidates->name_surname[x + j])
                break;
            j++;
        }
        if (j == temp1 && (candidates->name_surname[x + j] == 0 || candidates->name_surname[x + j] == '-'))
            temp3 = 1;

        if (upper_case == 1) {
            j = 1;
            while (j < temp2) {
                if (director.name_surname[num + temp1 + j] != candidates->name_surname[x + j])
                    break;
                j++;
            }
            if (temp2 == j && (candidates->name_surname[x + j] == 0 || candidates->name_surname[x + j] == '-'))
                temp3 = 1;
        }

        if (upper_case2 == 1) {
            j = 1;
            while (j < temp1) {
                if (director.name_surname[num + j] != candidates->name_surname[x + y + j])
                    break;
                j++;
            }
            if (j == temp1 && (candidates->name_surname[x + y + j] == 0 || candidates->name_surname[x + y + j] == '-'))
                temp3 = 1;
        }

        if (upper_case2 == 1 && upper_case == 1) {
            j = 1;
            while (j < temp2) {
                if (director.name_surname[num + temp1 + j] != candidates->name_surname[x + y + j])
                    break;
                j++;
            }
            if (j == temp2 && (candidates->name_surname[x + y + j] == 0 || candidates->name_surname[x + y + j] == '-'))
                temp3 = 1;
        }
        if (temp3 == 1) {
            candidates++;
            continue;
        }

        if (director.birth_date.year == candidates->birth_date.year) {
            if (divisible(director.birth_date.year) && candidates->birth_date.month > 2)
                candidates->birth_date.day++;
        
            A2 = candidates->birth_date.day + month(candidates->birth_date.month);

            if (num_days < A1 - A2) {
                ptr = candidates;
                j = i;
                while (j < size - 1) {
                    *ptr = *(ptr + 1);
                    ptr++;
                    j++;
                }
                size--; candidates--; i--;
            }
        }

        else if (director.birth_date.year - candidates->birth_date.year > s) {
            ptr = candidates;
            j = i;
            while (j < size - 1) {
                *ptr = *(ptr + 1);
                ptr++;
                j++;
            }
            size--; candidates--; i--;
        }

        candidates++;
    }
    return size;
}


int main() {
    /* AT4: The year 1900 was not a leap year */
    struct Employee director = { "Mujo Mujic", {1, 3, 1900} };
    struct Employee candidates[7] = {
        { "Meho Mehic", { 31, 1, 1900 } },
        { "Pero Peric", { 1, 2, 1900 } },
        { "Sara Sarac", { 2, 2, 1900 } },
        { "Fata Mujic", { 1, 2, 1896 } },
        { "Jozo Jozic", { 1, 10, 1900 } },
        { "Mijo Mijic", { 4, 3, 1899 } },
        { "Suljo Suljic", { 15, 1, 1902 } },
    };

    int new_size = narrow_down_list(candidates, 7, director, 28);
    int i;
    printf("After narrowing down the list:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < new_size; i++)
        printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name_surname);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The selection criteria are unclear, both in the description and in the code.  Is it that the birth dates need to be `num_days` of each other?  Also is there some reason you're not using `time.t` functions?

Comment: Yes they need to be num_days of each other. And you shouldn't eliminate the candidates that have the same surname as the director.

Comment: The string "name_surname" contains both the first and last name, separated by a space. It has been mentioned that some users may have two first names or two last names.

Comment: If a user has two first names, they are also separated by a space (e.g., "Ana Marija Kovacevic"). However, if a user has two last names, they must be exclusively separated by a hyphen, without any spaces (e.g., "Kolinda Grabar-Kitarovic"). In the case of two last names, it is required that either of those two last names matches with either of the other two last names. For example, if the director's last surname is "Mujic-Fatic" and the employee's last surname is "Fatic-Peric," they should not be excluded.

Comment: The code prints `Fata Mujic` even though the birthdays of the director are 4 years apart, much greater than 28 days.  Are you sure it's working?

Comment: @Edward but the directors surname is Mujic so she shouldn't be eliminated as planned

Comment: corruption at its finest :)

Comment: You must read [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/) and watch [The problem with time & timezones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY).

Comment: It would be useful to reviewers if you added those explanations to the text in the question and also explained why, for example, the code prints `Suljo Suljic` even though that person's birth date is more than 28 days from `Mujo Mujic` and they don't share a name.

Answer (score 2):

##### Don't reinvent the wheel:

`ctype.h` provides `isalpha()` to check if a character is an alphabet. Consider using that to your custom `is_letter()`.

##### `divisible()` is more aptly named as `is_leap_year()`:

Consider explicitly evaluating the results of the conditions, or leaving them altogether. You do `x % 400 == 0` and then do `x % 100`. I suggest:

```
if (x % 400 == 0) 
else if (x % 100 != 0) 

// OR
if (!(x % 400)
else if (x % 100)
```

The former is more readable.

##### Consider using `fputs()/puts()` to `fprintf()/printf()` when the formatting capabilities aren't required:

```
// printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name_surname);
puts(candidates[i].name_username);
```

Comment: At least `is_letter()` is _locale_ insensitive and `isalpha()` is.  An advantage or disadvantage for OP.

Comment: "fputs()/puts() to fprintf()/printf()" is a micro optimization as good compilers will emit efficient code either way.  Code for clarity and maintenance.